# Searching for data in a PDF

Tags: python, pdf

I've got a PDF file that I'm trying to obtain specific data from.

I've been able to parse the PDF via PyPDF2 into one long string but searching for specific data is difficult because of - I assume - formatting in the original PDF.

What I am looking to do is to retrieve specific known fields and the data that immediately follows (as formatted in the PDF) and then store these in seperate variables.

The PDFs are bills and hence are all presented in the exact same way, with defined fields and images. So what I am looking to do is to extract these fields.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: In general, it is probably impossible.

Comment: Try the tool called `pdfgrep`

Comment: What is the actual motivation of your question? In practice, where do the PDF files come from? Do you know how they have been produced?

Comment: The original location I am not entirely sure of, it's a large organisation so at this stage I don't have the resources to find out. What I do have is the PDFs, which are generated all in the same way and in the same format, with design/fields, the same in each.

Comment: Do you want a solution for one particular PDF file (or a selected collection of few of thems) or a general solution? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? What large organization provides that file? Does it has any interest for people to be able to *easily* extract data from it? Or one the contrary does it want to "hide" data inside it?

Comment: Without a lot more context and motivation, your question is unclear. Please **edit your question** to improve it a lot (add several paragraphs explaining your actual problem).

Comment: So it's for a selected few PDF files, not a general solution. My apologies for not being clear on that. I work for the large organisation in question and I am working on the solution with the PDFs I have been provided with by a completely seperate part of the company to which I am working in. The PDFs are bills, hence they are designed to be read by a human and not read back in again (I would assume).

Comment: That should go into the question. And since they are bills, there is certainly a better way to approach the problem (by asking some other access to these bills and the data inside them). At last, you need to be sure that you are legally allowed to extract such data from these PDF files. You might be trying to do something illegal, and that puts you in a big trouble.

Comment: I can't at this stage access the data in any other way, it has to come from the PDFs.

Comment: Yes I am authorised to access the data in question.

Answer (score 0):

> I've got a PDF file that I'm trying to obtain specific data from.

In general, it is probably **impossible** (or extremely difficult), and details (than you don't mention) are very important. Study in details the complex [PDF specification](https://www.iso.org/standard/63534.html). Notice that [PDF is (more or less accidentally) Turing complete](https://ask.metafilter.com/102833/Pushing-the-limits-of-PDFs-First-what-are-they) (so your problem is [undecidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem) in general, since equivalent to the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)).

For example, a normal human reader could read digits in the document as text, or as a JPEG image, etc. And in practice many PDF documents have such kind of data.... Practically speaking, PDF is an output-only format and is designed for screen displaying and printing, not for extracting data from it.

You need to understand how exactly that PDF file was generated (with what exact software, from what actual data). That could take a lot of time (maybe several years of full time reverse-engineering work) without help.

A much better approach is to contact the person or entity providing that PDF file and negotiate some way of accessing the actual data (or at least get detailed explanation about the generation of that particular PDF file). For example, if the PDF file is computed from some database, you'll better access that database.

Perhaps using metadata or comments in your PDF file might help in guessing how it was generated.

The source of the data might produce various kinds of PDF file. For example, my cheap scanner is able to produce PDF. But your program would have hard time in extracting some numerical data from it (because that kind of PDF is essentially wrapping a pixelated image à la JPEG) and would need to deploy image recognition techniques (i.e. [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Sadly, I will not be able to retrieve the data from elsewhere, at least at this stage. It comes from a variety of places and this product is more of a POC to see what can be done.

Comment: So in general, your problem is practically unsolvable. In practice, you might work quite hard to solve it for *some* (not all, not even most) PDF files.